# What actions are required when your app get an applicationWillResignActive call?

Tags: ios, ios4

This question [io3->ios4 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736633/what-is-need-to-upgrade-an-app-from-ios3-to-ios4) said to support applicationWillResignActive.  While implementing this call, I also implemented applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillEnterForeground.  However, I found that my app would crash.  After some debugging on the simulator I determined that I needed to reinitialize a key data structure in applicationWillEnterForeground.  So my question is how would I have known that from reading the documentation?  (In fact, I may be doing the wrong thing and just so happened to get it working again.)  Is there an exact description of what to do when these methods are called?

Thanks.

Comment: @Moshe: I had an UIImage and I was trying to use the <UIImage>.CGImage member.  This was no longer valid.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @Moshe: Also, does your answer imply that whatever I would normally do at program initialization, I should do at applicationWillEnterForeground?  If so, then I should really refactor my code and put all of the initialization there.  Does that sound right?  (Conversely, applicationDidEnterBackground should teardown everything and release all memory?)

Comment: Regarding the image data, it was probably cached during runtime and deleted while backgrounded. Yes, you should do refactor the code.

Comment: @Moshe: One last question:  How do I know what data is cached during runtime?  Is it all data structures which I have [* alloc] init] 'ed?

Comment: No, you can't know that. Certain things are cached, like images, but only when you use certain methods. (For example, `imageWithName:` will cache it, but `alloc]initWithImageName]` The documentation for individual classes will give detail when relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things you should do when supporting multitasking, is saving the state of your app when it enters the background, and reload it when it becomes active. (If you generate a new template in Xcode, you'll see this.) 
Saving state means writing any user preferences or data to disk. Reloading the state involves reading saved preferences and data, recreating any in memory data structures that might need it (like in your example you gave).

In most circumstances, there's little else you need to do. The only thing that would crash your app that is unique to multitasking would be trying to run code in the background for longer than the allotted amount of time, (which is 10 minutes.) Otherwise, it sounds like you have got other problems with your code.